# Update ingress routes to include namespace

Tags: traefik-ingress

How can i update the ingress routes to include the namespace as part of the route such that the same service can be deployed into multiple namespaces and still be accessed via ingress route. My ingress controller is Traefik

What i have done is to enabled the allcrossnamespace in the traefik yaml file and set it to true